# Simplifying a sum of ratio of complex exponentials to isolate a specific term

Tags: trigonometry, summation

Let $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$, and further let $P = [\psi_1, \psi_2, ..., \psi_k, ...]$ where $\psi_k \in \mathbb{R} \,\,\, \forall k$. Now, suppose I have the following sum:

$$\sum_{k \in P} \frac{sin(N\pi(a-\psi_k)) sin(N\pi(\psi_k-b)) } {sin(\pi(a-\psi_k))sin(\pi(\psi_k-b))} $$

In my application, $|P|\approx O(10^8) $, and I have to perform this sum numerous times for various combinations of $a,b$. Even with vectorization, this is taking a bit longer than I would like.

To try to speed things up, I'd like to pre-compute as much of the "common" portion of the sum as I can, so that with each new combination of $a,b$ I can apply a modification to get the result.

The problem I run into is this: no matter how I try to simplify things, I keep getting stuck with trying to bring a common term in the denominator out of the sum. It would be great if I could somehow split the expression into something involving $a, b$ and something involving $\psi_k$. But, I am not sure how to do this.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Am I barking up the wrong tree here?

Thanks!

Comment: The large number $N$ in the hundreds of millions is quite worrying, not for mathematical reasons, but computational ones. Setting aside the runtime, to what precision do you know the values of $\psi_k$, and with what precision do you want to know the final result?

Comment: Also, is the double-usage of $N$ (equal to the cardinality $|P|$ and present in the numerator of each term) intentional?

Comment: Hi @jwimberley:

2nd question first: the double usage is not intentional - that was my mistake. I will update.

The values $\psi_k$, as well as $a,b$ are all double-precision floating points. The other thing I can say about $a,b$ is that they are ratios with the same denominator. That is: $a,b \in \frac{1}{M}[-m:1:+m]$, and $m,M \in \mathbb{Z}, M>0$

Comment: Is N a small integer, in that case? I was particular worried about multiplying 1e8 by values $\psi_k$ with presumably measurement uncertainty much greater than double-precision error (e.g. 1e8 times an effectively single precision error would have O(1) errors in all the arguments of sine functions in the numerator), but small N seems more tractable.

Comment: $N \approx O(10^3)$, so much much smaller than $|P|$